# C++ / Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the error for my code, I don't know how can fix this, anyone can help me?

Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

**I see this error in line 12 on arr[i] and 2.0!**

**I use visual studio 2019**

```
int n,i,ev=0;
float arr[150];

cin >> n;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] % 2.0 == 0.0)
        ev++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if doing work with integer number is not a problem for you than you can try this code-

```
int n,i,ev=0;
int arr[150];

cin >> n;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        ev++;
}
```

The reason you are having the error is that modular operation with floating-point numbers is not supported. Please let me know if you have further query :)

Comment: I need to find float even numbers in array!

Comment: @AmirEslamzadeh That's a bit of a strange requirement. Are you sure?

Comment: Ah, guess not, since you've accepted this answer 

Answer (score 6):

It's what it says: the expression must have integral or unscoped type.

The line and column number points you to the `%` operation. [This is an integer modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Arithmetic_operators), which requires *integers*.

`2.0` is not an integer, and neither is `arr[i]`.

Use [`std::fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) instead.

**But** you're going to struggle here. Finding "even" floating-point numbers may be tricky, because floating-point numbers can be inexact. Decide whether you *really* need floats and, if you do, decide whether you *really* need to find out whether they're even whole numbers.